# Python Flask not returning Post data to React

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am having a problem with getting my flask backend to send a response back to my REACT js frontend. The following is the code used in REACT js frontend create a post request sending the string, 'message'. The flask backend should then send the string back and a console log will be created displaying the string.

**REACT JS**

```
        const response2 = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_TEST}`,{
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify('message'),
        }
        )
        
        console.log('The response was....', response2)
```

**Flask**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def index():
    print('Running')
    print 
    sent_data = request.get_json()
    print(sent_data)
    if sent_data != 'message':
        return ({"hello": ['no']})
    else:
        return (sent_data)
```

The data is picked up on the backend and prints "message" so information is getting to flask.
The issue is that instead of receiving the string 'message' logged in the React js console I get...

```
The response was.. {type: "cors", url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false}
```

If anything is unclear let me know and appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: I think you use `fetch` in wring way. It doesn't return `response` from server but only information where it send data - object `Promise`. You should use rather `fetch().then(...)` or `requests = await fetch()` and `requests.then(...)` like in doc [Using_Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: you may need to use `return jsonify(send_data)` and in react `response2 = response2.then(resp => resp.json())`

Comment: @furas that's solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never worked with React but I think you use `fetch` in wrong way.

It may give `Promise` instead of `response` and you should rather use

```
fetch(...)
.then( response => response.text() )
.then( text => {console.log('The response was....', text);} );
```

Or if you would use `return jsonify(send_data)` instead of `return send_data` then you would need `resonse.json()` instead of `response.text()`.
And then you would get `data["hello"]` if it would send `{"hello": ['no']}`

```
fetch(...)
.then( response => response.json() )
.then( data => {console.log('The response was....', data);} );
```

Mozilla doc: [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) and [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

---

Minimal working example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
TEST
<script>
async function test() {
    await fetch('/data', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  //credentials: 'include',
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                  body: JSON.stringify('message'),
                })
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(text => {console.log('The response was....', text);});
                //.then(response => response.json())
                //.then(data => {console.log('The response was....', data['hello']);});
}

test();
</script>
''')

@app.route("/data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def data():
    print('running: /data')
    
    data = request.get_json()
    print('data:', data)
    
    if data != 'message':
        return jsonify({'hello': ['no']})
    else:
        return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response2 = await (await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_TEST}`,{
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify('message'),
})).json()

console.log('The response was....', response2)
```